# How to navigate to another page without reloading the whole page in NextJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I notice that in NextJs, whenever I click on a `<Link>` to go to another page, it calls the `getInitialProps` even if that "another" page is the same page.

For instance, on `/profile` page, there are 2 components, one for "user information" and the other component for "list of orders" which is paginated. Both data used in "user information" and "list of orders" components are fetched from APIs in `getInitialProps` of the `/profile` page.

When I click to go to the next page of the "list of orders" component on `/profile` page, it goes to `/profile/p/2`. The data loads and it all works fine, except that `/profile/p/2` actually reloads the whole profile page and re-fetches the "user information" data which should have remained the same (and doesn't need to be re-fetched) as long as the page is part of `/profile` page.

Is there a way to navigate to `/profile/p/2` from `/profile` without reloading the whole page but only the component showing the list of orders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass shallow to Link like this

```
<Link href="...." as="...." shallow=true />
```

Comment: This doesn't work for distinct pages, because shallow routing is only for same-page updates.