# NextJS disabled getinitialProps if redirect by next/router or next/link

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have pages that has many api calls on getInitialProps and i use await on those api calls so it will render on server side but the problem is redirect takes too long to happen because it's waiting for the api call to finish.

My question is, is there anyway to disable getInitialProps if the client is redirected by next/router or next/link? I only want to use getInitialProps if only the client refresh or directly visit the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to navigate to another page without reloading the whole page in NextJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796012/how-to-navigate-to-another-page-without-reloading-the-whole-page-in-nextjs)

Comment: Shallow is exactly what i need! But it only works on the same page. Is there any nextjs function that works like shallow but also works on redirecting to different page?

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing in `next`, I will check out, but, have you considered using a query parameter in the url to ignore getInitialProps when you want to ignore it. such like`host/pathname?cl_redirect=true`, read it via query at the top of getInitialProps, still a possible work around.